# The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine error message

Tags: c#, asp.net

I don't get where i wrong.

when i work with local machine program run successfully.
but when i upload on server it will give an error like The **'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine**

```
           protected void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
      // try{
          string connectionstring = "";
          string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        string fileextension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        string filelocation = Server.MapPath("~/file/") + filename;
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(filelocation);
        if (fileextension == ".xlsx")
        {
            connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filelocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=2\"";
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from [Sheet1$]";
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            oda.Fill(dt);
            grvExcelData.DataSource = dt;
            Session["TaskTable"] = dt;
            grvExcelData.DataBind();
        }
      // }catch(Exception ex){Response.Write(ex.Message);  }
    }
```

error image 
    [image]

Comment: seems a very conclusive error message. Suggest you register it.

Comment: Is the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` driver installed on the server? If not i think you need to install this http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: @ Ben Robinson :- it an online sight http://dmkgcollege.in/whitecode/index.aspx see this link and how to install Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 on server. guide me

Comment: guide you? what does that mean? Are you unable to read the tutorial?

Comment: @ Ben Robinson :- how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Install the **32bit** OLEDB 12.0 driver on the server, you can find it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255). Alternatively, you can use something like the excellent [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) if you want to play around with (xml-based) excel files without installing stuff on the server.